# Connection/port issues with pure-ftp

Tags: linux, ftp, pureftpd

I setup pure-ftp on freebsd behind firewall. On pure-ftp setuped passsi mode ftp(rangle port 50400-50600) and firewall open port from 50400-50600 (include mode IN and out). But i try use ftp client connect but not connect. Nofinication error

```
status: Connecting to 210.245.88.96:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] ----------
Response:   220-You are user number 1 of 50 allowed.
Response:   220-Local time is now 13:20. Server port: 21.
Response:   220-IPv6 connections are also welcome on this server.
Response:   220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.
Command:    USER bk
Response:   331 User bk OK. Password required
Command:    PASS *****
Response:   230 OK. Current directory is /
Command:    SYST
Response:   215 UNIX Type: L8
Command:    FEAT
Response:   211-Extensions supported:
Response:    EPRT
Response:    IDLE
Response:    MDTM
Response:    SIZE
Response:    REST STREAM
Response:    MLST type*;size*;sizd*;modify*;UNIX.mode*;UNIX.uid*;UNIX.gid*;unique*;
Response:    MLSD
Response:    ESTA
Response:    PASV
Response:    EPSV
Response:    SPSV
Response:    ESTP
Response:   211 End.
Status: Connected
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is your current location
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (210,245,88,98,138,1)
Command:    MLSD
Error:  Connection timed out
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
Status: Connecting to 210.245.88.98:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
```

Help me.

Change by ibforrmation

Answer (score 0):

Opening ports are probably not enough, you probably also need to forward the port range back to your FTP server as well.

Comment: Add information. I have ip publish not by NAT

Comment: Then the opened port range should be bidirectional across the firewall.